# Add More One Formula In same cell from another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

Add More One Formula In same cell from another cell

Like That

```
=IF(H7="**cafee latee L**";**22**;0)<br />
```

the other formula that i want to add the same with different name and price

```
=IF(H7="**cafee latee R**";**19**;0)<br />
```

that mean if you find in H7 Word "`" put Price if find "`" put price ...etc

Answer (score 0):

Try using nested IF clause:
 `=IF(H7="cafee latee R",22,IF(H7="cafee latee L",19,0))`

Comment: @TonyFares I tried this again, and its working well for me!!, can you tell me the error you are facing while using the formula.

Comment: message is<br> the formula you typed contains an error<br> then it mark on       R",22,IF

Answer (score 0):

Although the answer by @identifymecnu will work but "Nesting IF" become really difficult to handle after ~10 items.

You can create a table (TEST) with two column headers (ITEM, VAL)
& populate every row with a new item & its value.

[image: TABLE]

Then use following formula :

**`=INDEX(TEST[VAL],MATCH(H7,TEST[ITEM],0))`**

[image]

Comment: i try it but i can't get it can you send me excel sheet have example

Comment: @TonyFares: I have added images for clarification. Sorry, I do not know how to provide an excel sheet in Stackoverflow !!